# Use RFECV in linear regression pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to use sklearn RFECV to perform feature selection. So I wrote below code to identify optimal no of features.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV,RFE
rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=LinearRegression(),
    step=1,
    cv=folds,
    scoring="r2",
    min_features_to_select=2,
    n_jobs=2,
)
rfecv.fit(X, y)
print(f"Optimal number of features: {rfecv.n_features_}")
```

Output of above code is 6 which means RFECV recommends 6 feature to select for best model performance.

When I try to use RFECV in regression pipeline as below:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV,RFE
rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=LinearRegression(),
    step=1,
    cv=folds,
    scoring="r2",
    min_features_to_select=2,
    n_jobs=2,
)

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s',rfecv),('m',LinearRegression())])
# fit the model on all available data
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
pipeline.n_features_in_
```

**pipeline.n_features_in_ returns 215 which is the total number of features in my train dataset. I was expecting pipeline.n_features_in_ to return 6**. Also, with above pipeline , I don't see any difference in X_test prediction  score when compared linear regression result without any feature selection.

I am trying to understand why in pipeline, pipeline.n_features_in_ returns 215 rather than 6 ? As per my understanding , 1st step of the pipeline would fit and transform X_train dataset and then transformed data set would be passed to linearRegression() .

Is my understanding of above pipeline correct?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs of `Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline):

> n_features_in_ ***: int***
> Number of features seen during first step `fit` method.

So you get the number of features before any step has been actually performed. If you want the number of features after `RFECV` then e.g. check the `n_features_in_` attribute of the `LinearRegression` step:

```py
pipeline['m'].n_features_in_
```

where `pipeline['m']` returns the `LinearRegression` object.